# Object comparison and array sorting in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, strcmp, object-comparison

I have a problem with object comparison in PHP. What seems like a straightforward code actually runs way *too slow* for my liking and as I am not that advanced in the language I would like some feedback and suggestions regarding the following code:

```
class TestTokenGroup {
    private $tokens;
    ...

    public static function create($tokens) {
        $instance = new static();
        $instance->tokens = $tokens;
        ...
        return $instance;
    }

    public function getTokens() {
        return $this->tokens;
    }

    public static function compare($tokenGroup1, $tokenGroup2) {
        $i = 0;
        $minLength = min(array(count($tokenGroup1->getTokens()), count($tokenGroup2->getTokens())));
        $equalLengths = (count($tokenGroup1->getTokens()) == count($tokenGroup2->getTokens()));
        $comparison = strcmp($tokenGroup1->getTokens()[$i], $tokenGroup2->getTokens()[$i]);
        while ($comparison == 0) {
            $i++;
            if (($i == $minLength) && ($equalLengths == true)) {
                return 0;
            }
            $comparison = strcmp($tokenGroup1->getTokens()[$i], $tokenGroup2->getTokens()[$i]);
        }
        $result = $comparison;
        if ($result < 0)
            return -1;
        elseif ($result > 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    ...

}
```

In the code above `$tokens` is just a simple array of strings.

Using the method above through `usort()` for an array of `TestTokenGroup` consisting of around 40k objects takes ~2secs.

Is there a sensible way to speed that up? Where is the bottleneck here?

EDIT: Added the getTokens() method I initially forgot to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that objects are "pass by reference", and arrays are "pass by value"?

If `getTokens()` returns `$this->tokens`, the array is copied every time you invoke that method.

Try accessing `$tokens` directly via `$tokenGroup1->tokens`. You could also use references (`&`) although returning a reference doesn't work in all PHP versions.

Alternatively, make one copy only:

```
$tokens1 = $tokenGroup1->getTokens();
$tokens2 = $tokenGroup2->getTokens();
```

Even if each token group is relatively small, it will save at least `40000 * ( 6 + $average_token_group_length * 2)` array copies.

**UPDATE**

I've benchmarked OP's code (removing the `...` lines) using:

```
function gentokens() {
        $ret = [];
        for ( $i=0; $i< 3; $i++)
        {
                $str = "";
                for ( $x = rand(0,3); $x < 10; $x ++ )
                        $str .= chr( rand(0,25) + ord('a') );
                $ret[] = $str;
        }
        return $ret;
}


$start = microtime(true);

$array = [];    // this will hold the TestTokenGroup instances
$dummy = "";    // this will hold the tokens, space-separated and newline-separated
$dummy2= [];    // this will hold the space-concatenated strings

for ( $i=0; $i < 40000; $i++)
{
        $array[] = TestTokenGroup::create( $t = gentokens() );

        $dummy   .= implode(' ', $t ) . "\n";
        $dummy2[] = implode(' ', $t );
}

// write a test file to benchmark GNU sort:
file_put_contents("sort-data.txt", $dummy);

$inited = microtime(true);
printf("init: %f s\n", ($inited-$start));

usort( $array, [ 'TestTokenGroup', 'compare'] );

$sorted = microtime(true);
printf("sort: %f s\n", ($sorted-$inited));

usort( $dummy2, 'strcmp' );

$sorted2 = microtime(true);
printf("sort: %f s\n", ($sorted2-$sorted));
```

With the following results:

```
init: 0.359329 s    // for generating 40000 * 3 random strings and setup
sort: 1.012096 s    // for the TestTokenGroup::compare
sort: 0.120583 s    // for the 'strcmp' compare
```

And, running `time sort sort-data.txt > /dev/null` yields

```
.052 u  (user-time, in seconds).
```

**optimisation 1: remove array copies**

replacing `->getTokens()` with `->tokens` yields (I'll only list the `TestTokenGroup::compare` results):

```
sort: 0.832794 s
```

**Optimisation 2: remove redundant `array()` in `min`**

Changing the `$minlength` line to:

```
$minLength = min(count($tokenGroup1->tokens), count($tokenGroup2->tokens));
```

gives

```
sort: 0.779134 s
```

**Optimisation 3: Only call `count` once for each `tokenGroup`**

```
    $count1 = count($tokenGroup1->tokens);
    $count2 = count($tokenGroup2->tokens);
    $minLength = min($count1, $count2);
    $equalLengths = ($count1 == $count2);
```

gives

```
sort: 0.679649 s
```

**Alternative approach**

The fastest sort so far is `strcmp( $stringarray, 'strcmp' )`: 0.12s - still twice as slow as GNU sort, but the latter only does one thing, and does it well.

So, to sort the TokenGroups efficiently we need to construct sort key consisting of a simple string. We can use `\0` as a delimiter for the tokens, and we don't have to worry about them being equal length, because as soon as one character is different, the compare aborts.

Here's the implementation:

```
$arr2 = [];
foreach ( $array as $o )
  $arr2[ implode("\0", $o->getTokens() ) ] = $o;

$init2 = microtime(true);
printf("init2: %f s\n", ($init2-$sorted2));

uksort( $arr2, 'strcmp' );

$sorted3 = microtime(true);
printf("sort: %f s\n", ($sorted3-$init2));
```

and here the results:

```
init2: 0.125939 s
sort: 0.104717 s
```

Comment: So what you are saying is basically - if there is an object field which is an array, never write a getter for it, rather make it public and access it as such directly?

Comment: Not necessarily; it is usually all right, but sorting a 40k list will at worse require 1.6 trillion comparisons, and in that case you have to consider the overhead... You can keep the field private; your method should be able to access the fields - I think. I'm curious whether avoiding array copies improves the timing?

Comment: If it does, it is only marginally. Sadly, it still takes more than a second to sort the objects. The `$tokens` arrays are actually with only 3 elements for the example I am using and won't be much lengthier in the real environment.

Comment: That's already nearly twice as fast - pretty significant. I wonder how much time is spent in the rest of the program, constructing the 40k array etc. Could you time just the `usort()` (by using `getmicrotime(true)`)?

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. From around ~1.4 - 1.7 seconds for the `usort()` alone, I got to ~1.2 - 1.4 seconds.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Yes, it makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your effort. I consider this a thorough research and answer to my question.